# How do i know that an infinite integral converge?

Tags: integration

I've recently learned about QFT path integrals and i would like to know how to make sure a series of infinite integral converge. Making sure an infinite summation isn't hard and infinite product is basically and infinite summation exponentiation, so we can use the same technique(except if variables doesn't commute). But say that i have [image]

Where $q_i,p_i$ are functions of time and $q_{i+1}(t),p_{i+1}(t)=q_i(t+\delta t),p_i(t+\delta t)$, $\bar{q_i}=\frac{q_i+q_{i+1}}{2}$ and $e^{-iH\delta t}$ is a gaussian function of $p$ and $q$ decays as a negative exponential, how do i know that it converges?